# How to graft a plum tree

Tags: pruning, growth, grafting, plums

these days I am going to prune my plum tree, I will perform the pruning following the guidelines of [this article that talks about pruning a plum tree](https://comoycuandopodar.com/ciruelo/) (it is in Spanish but nothing that Google translator cannot solve;)).

The prune plum is a very strong tree that gives a very good amount of fruits, in addition they are of very good quality. On the other hand, this plant already has a good number of years, so I think it does not have so many years of life.

From there arises my need to create a new plant to prepare to replace the one I already have. I have some small specimens that I have been born from seed, and I would like to graft them. My idea is to take advantage and at the same time that I prune the adult plum, select good yolks to perform the grafting.

Faced with this I would like you to guide me on how to make the grafting of my plum. I have searched for information on Google but the truth is that there is not much, I would appreciate your advice. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

My tip: ask a professional. The costs on having the correct knife, mastic, etc. is often higher (for sure for my success rate). if it is a good old variety, some professionals / nurseries may make it for free (or better in exchange of some branches for them).

The root part of a grafted plant should have a good variety/species for your soil. From seed is often not a good idea (but if you are in the region where plums growth naturally). Grafting is done for two reasons: clone of the good part, but also good roots for your soil. On very old past, varieties were much linked to soil because of this.

In other cases: select branches with the same size as the seedling you will to prune. This makes things much simpler. You can find in Youtube many methods: a video is worth more than words I can write, and you really see how things are done, just check various of them.

Do it in spring. Sap should be flowing (or just before of them), so that no fungi or diseases could enter in the graft. Eventually keep some branches not pruned for such reason.

Comment: Thank you Giacomo Catenazzi for your advice. In the end, my father-in-law solved the problem for me. My new plant is ready to be transplanted. :)